# How can I prove these polynomials are minimal?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

We're considering the extension field $\mathbb R$ of $\mathbb Q$

The first element is $2+\sqrt3$ over $\mathbb Q$.

The polynomial I have is $a^4 - 14a^2 + 1.$

The second element is $\sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ over $\mathbb Q$.

The polynomial I have is $a^4 - 16a^2 + 4.$

Comment: The first one is not the minimal polynomial of $2+\sqrt{3}$. I think you mean $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: WolframAlpha confirms 2 + $\sqrt3$ is a root of the polynomial.

Comment: Oh okay then you don't mean $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. But it is still not the minimal polynomial because $2+\sqrt{3}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ which is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $2$. Hence the minimal polynomial of an element has degree at most $2$.

Comment: I have no idea on how to find that minimal polynomial, then.

edit: figured it out. $a^2 - 4a - 7$.

Comment: $2+\sqrt{3}$ is not a root of $a^2-4\cdot a-7$.

Comment: Then I really have no idea on how to compute this minimal polynomial. I tried the only method I know and it didn't work. Edit: Apparently I made an arithmetic error. Which is exactly why I can't stand this topic.

Comment: A useful way to try to determine the minimal polynomial in this case is to set $x=2+\sqrt{3}$, square it, expand it, write all the radical terms on one side, and square again until the radicals disappear and you’re left with a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Now a priori, it’s possible that this isn’t the minimal polynomial so you must check that it is, by determining whether it’s irreducible or not. If yes, you win, if not, factor and show one of those is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: You end up with $a^4-14\cdot a^2+1$. I don't think factoring this polynomial is elementary.

Answer (score 3):

$2+\sqrt{3}$ is an element of $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ which is generated as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space by $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$. Since $E$ is an extension of degree $2$, any element of this field has minimal polynomial of degree at most $2$.

Consider the map $f:E\rightarrow E$ defined as $f(x)=x\cdot(2+\sqrt{3})$. This is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map. Let's write it as a matrix :

$f(1) = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $f(\sqrt{3})=2\cdot\sqrt{3}+3$.

Hence the matrix is $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ which has the characteristic polynomial $f(x)=det(A-x\cdot I)=(2-x)^2-3=x^2-4\cdot x +1$. Check that this polynomial admits $2+\sqrt{3}$ as a root. $f$ is the minimal polynomial we are looking for.

Can you apply the same method for $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$?

Edit : The minimal polynomial of $2+\sqrt{3}$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ by definition. You can show that in fact this polynomial must be $(x-2-\sqrt{3})\cdot (x-2+\sqrt{3})=x^2-4\cdot x +1$ since if $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a root then the conjugate $2-\sqrt{3}$ also must be a root. Similarly compute the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$.

Edit 2 : There is an easier way to show that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is $a^4-16\cdot a^2+4$. Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ has extension degree $4$ hence the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is either $2$ or $4$. If the minimal polynomial is $x^2-d\cdot x -c$ then we could write $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2=c+d\cdot(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$. Note that $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2=8+2\cdot\sqrt{15}$ which is not of this form. Hence the minimal polynomial has degree $4$. Now check that the given polynomial admits $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ as a root.

Comment: My knowledge of linear algebra is pretty limited; do you have a technique from a field theory perspective?

Comment: I don't know how one can avoid linear algebra in field theory but yes I can. I'll edit.

Comment: The class is a second semester of modern algebra, so linear isn't in the toolbox we're using.

Comment: Okay then. I edited my answer with a different method to compute the minimal polynomial.

Comment: I have the minimal polynomial, but how do I prove it as such?

Comment: It has degree $2$. If it is not minimal then the minimal polynomial would have degree $1$ so the given element would be rational (but it is not).

Answer (score 0):

$2 + \sqrt{3}$ is a root of $(x - 2)^2 - 3$. Since $x^2 - 3$ is irreducible, so is $(x - 2)^2 - 3$.

$\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is a root of $(x^2 - 8)^2 - 60 = x^4 - 16x^2 + 4$, as you found. You can show that $x^4 - 16x^2 + 4$ is irreducible by trying to factor it explicitly, or you can show that the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]$ is equal to $4$.

For the first approach: $x^4 - 16x^2 + 4 = 0$ has no rational solutions. By the rational root theorem we only need to check $x = \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4$, and there is no need to check negatives because we only have even powers of $x$. A factorization of the polynomial into quadratics has to look like $(x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$. We get four equations: $a + c = 0, ac + b + d = -16, ad + bc = 0, bd = 4$. The first implies $a = -c$, and the third then implies $b = d$ or $a = c = 0$. If $a = c = 0$, equations 2 and 4 become $b + d = -16$ and $bd = 4$, which has no integer solutions. If $b = d = \pm 2$, equation 2 becomes $-a^2 \pm 4 = -16$, which also has no integer solutions.

For the second approach: We have $(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})^2 = 8 + 2\sqrt{15}$, meaning there is a sequence of field extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{15}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}]$. Since $\sqrt{15}$ is not rational, the first extension is of degree 2. Then we just need to show $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{15}]$. If it were, we would have $a + b\sqrt{15} = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$, and squaring both sides gives $a^2 + 15b^2 = 8$, and $2ab = 2$ Writing $b = 1/a$, we can simplify the first equation to become $a^4 - 8a^2 + 15 = 0$, or $(a^2 - 3)(a^2 - 5) = 0$, which clearly has no rational solutions.

Note that the second approach generalizes easily to any number of the form $\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q}$, as long as $p,q,pq$ are all not perfect squares.